# What is the way to write tests against a 3rd party software like redis

Tags: javascript, php, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question if not kindly point me in the right direction.

I wanted to create a library/client for a 3rd party tool, which is similar to redis. And for the unit/integration tests, I see that in [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) library, they have tests which directly interacts with a running redis instance and there are tests which make use of mocks.

So my question is that, is it okay if I write tests running against an actual instance of the 3rd party tool or should I employ mocks all the way?

Comment: What are you testing? Are you testing the tool or your code? If you are testing the 3rd party tool, that would be a bit unusual but you can just write a unit test and treat it as a black box. I guess it can work if you decide to swap that 3rd party tool for something else and want to ensure the new one would behave the same way as you expect. On the other hand, if you're testing your own code, you shouldn't really care about that tool. Ideally you'd mock it in unit tests because you want to isolating your functionality. But you can also leave it if it's at least one of a) hard b) insignificant

Comment: yes. I was looking for this, I should treat it as blackbox. If you can write it as an answer it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing unit tests it is important to only test the functionality you are interested in. When you have a third party library, you are interested in one of two things when running a test:

## Does the third party software behave correctly

You can write a test for a third party library and treat the tool as a [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing), so you aren't testing the *internals* but if it *behaves* consistently. Pseudo code of such a test

```
//testing if a value is automatically timestamped
expected = "expected value"
tool.setValue("myKey", expected)

actual = tool.getValue("myKey")

assertThat(actual, endsWith(expected))
assertThat(actual, startsWith(dateToday()))
```

This test will formalises your assumptions and expectations about the behaviour and can be useful if you change the third party tool and want to see if it still behaves as you expect it to. You don't care about the internals, just how you use it. This can be useful to verify when upgrading to a newer version of the tool itself or if you switch to an alternative and want to ensure it works the same way. Important to note is that it works the same way, as far as your expectations go - whatever you change to could be faster or maybe communicate over the network or have some other effect that you don't care about.

## Does your code behave correctly

In this case, you'd be writing a test that only tests your own code. Unit tests isolate the functionality, so you can replace that tool with a mock, in order to only verify your own code is correct. For example, if you switch to a new version of the tool that doesn't do timestamps, do don't want your test to for external reasons.

Here is a sample pseudo code of what a test will look like:

```
//check your code inserts the correct values without modifying them
mockTool = mock(SomeThirdPartyTool)
testInstance = new MyClass(mockTool)

expected = "some value"
expect(mockTool.insertValue()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

testInstance.insertValue(expected)

assertThat(expectationSatisfied())
```

In this case, changes to the third party tool would not influence the test. If you change the configuration to add or remove a timestamp to the value, the test will still be correct. It would fail if you manually add a timestamp in your code. This is exactly what you want - your test only fails for one clear reason.